# What is the Paypal "Identity Token" or "Token ID" and what is it used for?

Tags: paypal, checkout, hosted

2 questions for you regarding Paypal Hosted Checkout solution and the goal of the "Identity Token" or "Token ID".

1-
I've come accross several online Paypal docs (such as for Payflow integration) that talk about providing the "Identity Token" (or "Token ID", I think they're the same do they?), but I was wondering what's the goal of passing over this token ID, is it for my own security, or Paypal's one, or something else? Does anybody know exactly what's the purpose of that token ID, what Paypal is doing with it, and/or what the vendor shall be doing with it?

Asking this because when doing the form post to redirect the user to the Paypal hosted checkout, we have to first call the paypal gateway server to obtain the "secure token" and this API call is already secured through another method right, I need to pass my account credentials. So why posting only the "secure token" is not enough and we also need to post that "token ID"? Paypal should already have associated the secure token with my account information through the first API call no?

2-
Also, at the end of the flow, once Paypal returns the customer to my vendor website, does Paypal include any of those tokens (token ID or secure token) as part of their request (perhaps by adding url parameters to my given vendor return url)? If so, does Paypal recommands any sort of validation to be made on the vendor side, such as validating that the tokens match the ones that I, the vendor, stored in the user session prior to redirecting the customer through a form post to the Paypal hosted checkout? Basically, how can I ensure that the session was not hijacked between the time I redirect the customer to Paypal hosted checkout and the time Paypal returns the customer back to my site?

Reference:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#hosted-checkout-pages

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As the previous user states, the Token id is used basically to identify an specific transaction process during it's workflow.

About your second question, in case of Express Checkout, the workflow does not ends when PayPal returns the user to your site. This step you are describing is probably when you send the user to PayPal to AUTHORIZE a payment that you will issue later. The last step is the DoExpressCheckoutPayment, in which you just inform paypal to make the transaction, for this you just pass to PayPal the token, so PayPal knows what you are "talking" about.

Is it good practice to validate the token, I would say yes. Somebody might be listening at your connection and injecting some invalid token. In any case, if you send an invalid token you will get an error message from paypal.

the following image illustrates very good the whole process:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (and if reading this correctly), the Secure Token is for processing transactions on your own site instead of passing the user and order to paypal for processing. The Secure Token identifies that specific transaction and ensures the continuity of the order is not broken. You require a Token ID in order to obtain a Secure Token.